# run Python code within IDE without python installed in the system

Tags: python, compilation, ide, interpreter

I am working on a Python IDE to be used by kids, where I have two panes: one for editing the source code, say 'a.py'; one for showing the output of 'python a.py' if one run it from a terminal. However I expect the IDE to work in system where no python installation at all. How can I achieve this?

The closest thing I found is code.InteractiveInterpreter(), but I hope there is something easier like 'eval('a.py'). Any suggestions?

Comment: no really. I will make my IDE standalone, but within the IDE, the user still needs to run his/her script.

Comment: create instalator which installs IDE and Python.

Comment: `eval()` needs Python to execute it. Better install Python.

Comment: You cannot run dynamic Python scripts/code without Python. Your best bet is that the IDE comes with its own Python installer or setup scripts, then runs all the codes inside its own virtual environment.